# Scheduled refresh for Power Bi dataset with data from an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, powerbi, refresh, schedule

According to the Microsoft page you have to do that by publishing the Excel sheet to Power Bi
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-excel-workbook-files (blue box in the beginning). This is valid since 29th of September so the old tutorials do not work anymore because they disabled the option for scheduled refresh if you do it like in the tutorials
If I do that the scheduled refresh option doesn't show up in PowerBi

[Excel_publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFX5t.png)

I formatted my data as a table and went to publish in the file tab. Then I tried both options upload and export but for neither of them in Power Bi the scheduled refresh option shows up in the settings of Power Bi. Do I need connections in the Excel sheet or is it just fine if they are formatted as tables?
Please help
[PowerBi Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKgyG.png)

Comment: That article and blue box are stating that is no longer possible. Upload your Excel file to OneDrive/SharePoint, then in Power BI, Get Data from that Excel in OneDrive/SharePoint.